# PHP: Set name for image data URI

Tags: php

I'm stuck with a little problem and can't find a solution. I'm outputting my images to the website as base64 data URI. If someone opens the image directly in the browser the url to the image would be the data URI which works find but the name that shows in the browser tab is something random and i want to change that. I know that i could add `/new+name++that+i+want` at the end of the data URI to change the title that shows in the browser but sometimes there is already a name/title at the end of the data URI and in this case it would just create an error if I add something to the end. Is there any save way to set a title/name rather than adding something at the end and hoping it doesn't create an error?

Thanks for reading and have a nice day.

My Code:

```
$img = "uploads/images/smile.png";
$filetype = mime_content_type($img);
$imgdata = base64_encode(file_get_contents($img));
$src = "data:" . $filetype . ";base64," . $imgdata;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pathinfo` for file type `$filetype = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

```
$img = "uploads/images/smile.png";
$filetype = pathinfo($img, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$imgdata = base64_encode(file_get_contents($img));
$src = "data:" . $filetype . ";base64," . $imgdata;
```

Comment: Is there any reason for it? Because it doesn't change the file name :)

Comment: Output of 'mime_content_type' is  `image/png` but we want only `png`

Comment: But the data URI requires `image/png` if i try to open it with just `png` it shows an error